# How to stop this for-loop?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, break

```
var number = prompt("Typ some numbers:")
var som = 0

for (var x = 0; x < number.length; x++) {
  if (!(number[x] === 0)) {
    if ((number[x] % 2) === 1) {
      som += (number[x] * number[x])
    }
  } else {
    break;
  }
}

alert(som)
```

I want to type some random numbers (0-9) and then it must say the som of the Square of all the odd numbers before I type zero. For example I type: 5903. 5*5 + 9*9 = 106. So AFTER I type a zero it must STOP the for loop of going further. But right now if I typ 5903 it says 115, so right now it still DOES count 3*3 extra. So how do I make it stop after I type a zero? It doesn't work right now, it goes on after I type a zero. Someone know what's the problem? Maybe syntax?

Comment: The type of the value returned from `prompt` is _always_  string ...

Comment: Use `==` instead of `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

```
if (!(number[x] === 0)) {
```

to

```
if (number[x] !== '0') {
```

because you are comparing strings.

Working example:

```js
var number = prompt("Typ some numbers:"),
    som = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < number.length; x++) {
    if (number[x] !== '0') {
        if ((number[x] % 2) === 1) {
            som += (number[x] * number[x]);
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
alert(som);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if the number is equal to 0, but your number is actually '0'

you need to parse the input as an integer  or you can use double equals

```
var number = prompt("Typ some numbers:");
var som = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < number.length; x++){
  if(number[x] == 0){
    break;
  }  
  if ((number[x] % 2) === 1) {
     som += (number[x] * number[x]);
  }

}

alert(som);
```